# Как cериализовать xlsx c#?

Tags: c#, excel

Хотел бы получить 6 классов Types, Sst, relations, workbook, styleSheet, worksheet готовых к сериализации.  Может у кого есть готовые...? Формату уже более 10 лет...

Есть ли у кого наработки вроде

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName="sst", Namespace="Test")]
public class sst{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public int count;

   [XmlAttribute]
   public int uniqueCount;

   [XmlElement(ElementName="si",Namespace="")]
   public string si = new string[] {"string1","string2"};
    }
//...
```

Comment: А [OpenXML sdk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) не подходит?